# Can pybind11 be used with an existing manually written Python API?

Tags: pybind11

My C++ library already has a pretty significant manually written Python API using the Python C API. I don't want to significantly change my existing code, but some of the functions in pybind11 would be really convenient.

Is it possible to integrate pybind11 with an existing manually written API? I.e. would it be possibly to just do:

```
static PyObject *object_stuff(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) {
    int i = do_stuff(...);
    return py::cast(i);
}
```

And keep my existing python module and type definition C code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pybind11 does offer you to wrap existing python code. More about it can be found in the [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/object.html#accessing-python-libraries-from-c).

It can be accessed by creating python objects.

```
py::object scipy = py::module::import("scipy");
return scipy.attr("__version__");
```